# Homework check - critical region

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

The question: You would like to test null hypothesis that the height of adult women is equal to 169 cm versus the alternative that it is smaller. Sample variance 49, sample size 144. Find the critical region for confidence level of 90%. Assume that the heights are normally distributed.

$H_0: \mu = 169$ $H_A: \mu < 169$ $\alpha = 0.1$

To find critical value of sample mean I will normalize it and compare it to critical value of z-score.

$Z=\frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{\sigma_{\bar X}}=\frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{\frac{\sqrt{s^2}}{\sqrt n}}=\frac{12}{7}(\bar X - 169)$

$z_{\frac{1}{10}}=-1.28$

All in all $RR = \{(\bar X - 169)*\frac{12}{7} < -1.28\} \iff \bar X < 168.25 $

So the null gets rejected with confidence level of 90% if the sample mean is below 168.25cm

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: done as requested

Comment: Check your second to last line that starts "All in all RR"...looks like you may have inadvertently "flipped" something

Comment: Oh, right. Typing error :)